# Celery: custom Task/Request attribute shared with Queue

Tags: python, celery, amqp, celery-task

There is a tracker class, that just counts `success`, `failed`, `pending`, and `started` tasks via redis.

The goal is to extend Celery, so its workers can access the `group_id` and keep statistics for the group. I expect an interface similar to:

```py
def on_important_event(...):
    group_id=uuid4()
    for _ in range(count_of_jobs):
        my_task.apply_async(..., group_id=group_id)
```

custom Task class would look like:

```py
class MyTask(Task):
    # declaring group_id somehow
    def apply_async(...):
        get_tracker(self.request.group_id).task_pending()
        ...

    def before_start(...):
        get_tracker(self.request.group_id).task_started()
        ...

    def on_success(...):
        get_tracker(self.request.group_id).task_success()
        ...

    def on_failure(...):
        get_tracker(self.request.group_id).task_failed()
        ...
```

I could not find a way to implement the class so it will properly save and receive custom attribute through `AMQP`.

---

UPD, to make clear:

The problem is to mark some calls of Tasks as a participant of a group. So I can track the group not general Task or a single call.

As it seems to me, there must be a way to add an attribute for Task that would be saved into Queue and then received by a Celery's worker so i can access it on Task class layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different approach - write a custom monitor (check the Monitoring API document in the official Celery docs). A good starting point: [Real-time processing](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html?highlight=monitor#real-time-processing).

This is basically how Flower and [Leek](https://tryleek.com/) work.

Comment: I found the information helpful, but it doesn't solves my issue.  Added clarifying information for the question.